# Каким образом проверить целостность данных в Udp протоколе?

Tags: udp, tcp-ip

Данные шифруются публичным ключом, а доступ к ним будет через приватный ключ. По примеру openssl. Размер данных неограничен, но думаю будет от 1 до 5 кб.

Пример шифрованной строки 32j3223nfiu23n23iJFk32mm2.....

Если передавать по tcp, то накладно, т.к сеть пиринговая.

Как узнать целостность таких данных при передаче через Udp, а также как узнать, что за чем должно быть в сообщении?

Идеи.

Как я понимаю, если размер данных 300 байт, то сначала могут прийти 100-120 байти, затем 60-90 т.д

Comment: > Как узнать целостность таких данных при передаче через Udp

так же, как в tcp - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

> что за чем должно быть в сообщении?

насколько понимаю (на низком уровне так ни разу и не работал) - аналогично, придется вставлять порядковый номер пакета и общее количество/флаг последнего пакета.

Comment: @Etki хорошо. 1 ответ вроде понял. Теперь второй. Например, передается сообщения "привет", пусть после шифровки получится пиетвр. Как я понимаю размер передаваемого пакета один (**какой?**). Например, пусть будет 3 символа. Тогда я пишу пи1eт2вт3 и так обрабатываю. Кроме того, если нумеровать пакеты, то например в 1-ом пакете, можно передать количество пакетов.

Comment: @dal, я еще раз повторюсь, что не знаком близко с udp, но, насколько понимаю, придется не модифицировать исходное сообщение, а самому генерировать или отслеживать и модифицировать исходящие пакеты. Но в целом пример верный.

upd UDP поддерживает опциональное поле checksum, я опять же не знаю как конкретно заставить сокет его использовать, но верификация целостности может произведена посредством UDP.

Comment: @dal, лучше не гадать о свойствах UDP протокола, а сначала почитать (например, [здесь](http://www.soslan.ru/tcp/tcp11.html)).

Если коротко, то дейтаграммы могут теряться, но не фрагментироваться (на уровне сокетов, которыми Вы пользуетесь). 

Вся работа с фрагментацией происходит "ниже", незаметно для программиста.

Вообще-то в UDP уже есть встроенный механизм контрольных сумм и поврежденные пакеты Вы не получите.

Если не доверяете CRC (IMHO в UDP используется он), то добавьте свой (скажем, MD5).

Comment: @avp то есть udp сам вычисляет хеши и передает их в пакетах. После получения пакета он сам произведет вычисления и скажет была ли ошибка, все ли пришло. Сам произведет сбор пакетов, после чего выдаст все данные вместе. Только в отличии от tcp не отправляет пакет на готовность приема и не отправляет отправителю подтверждения доставке и не запрашивает данные, в случаи если что-то не пришло.

Comment: @dal, да, именно так.

--

Заметьте, что когда Вы используете tcp, то данные представлены *потоком* байт и границы между данными, отправляемыми  последовательными send() (или write) определить невозможно. При чтении recv() (или read) может вернуть меньше байт, чем было запрошено, но последующий recv() будет читать начиная с еще не прочитанных байт. В общем, все байты будут последовательно прочитаны.

А вот udp пакеты recv() читает полностью и по пакету за раз. Надо всегда запрашивать максимальный из возможного размера пакетов, поскольку непрочитанный "хвост" udp пакета сбрасывается.

Comment: @dal, немного невнимательно прочел вчера Ваш комментарий. 

--

Небольшое уточнение. Вы пишете:

       После получения пакета он сам произведет вычисления и скажет была ли ошибка, все ли пришло.

IMHO это не совсем так (реально проверить сложно, косвенно о таком поведении можно судить по значениям `errno` после `recv()` (см. man 2 recv)). 

Если была ошибка в данных (контрольная сумма), то система молча выбросит всю udp посылку (ну, в счетчиках ядра что-то зафиксирует) и Ваш `recv()` *никак на это не отреагирует*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Разбиваете данные на блоки по одному килобайту.
2. Считаете 4-байтный хеш от пары {номер блока, сам блок}. (В TCP этот хеш двух-байтный)
3. В UDP-пакеты вкладываете: {хеш пары, номер блока, сам блок}.
4. На принимающей стороне перезапрашиваете битые пакеты и те что не пришли, и склеиваете блоки согласно указанному порядку.

Эти манипуляции приведут вас к протоколу с контролем целостности и доставки. Примерно тоже самое реализовано в TCP. Поэтому я рекомендую вам не выполнять пункты 1-4, а использовать TCP. BitTorrent, например, до 2008 года использовал только TCP. *(Это, правда, если вам не критичен высокий пинг из-за тройного рукопожатия)*.